# Can't Access Server With Using 3g, 4g or LTE

Tags: node.js, react-native, networking, 3g, 4g

I have a Node.js server and mobile React Native client application. 
After switching to static ip, I can not connect to application server using mobile data. Mobile devices or computers which uses wifi can take response from my server but any device using mobile data can not. If my client application switch to wifi it reaches server perfectly but when I switch back to mobile data it throws 'network error'. Additionally anyone using mobile data can reach server with Chrome Mobile but other mobile browsers can't.

**Summary:**

- Chrome can access server with wifi, 3g, 4g, LTE.
- My application and any browser can access server with wifi.
- My application and the browsers except Chrome can not access server with 3g, 4g and LTE.

I am really confusing about this situation. Can this problem related with internet provider? or I need to add same configuration to server application for coming request from who uses mobile data? any ideas? Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Do you want to connect to server on localhost from external network?

Comment: I want to connect to server with my static ip from external network. Actually I can when I am using wifi but when I switch back to mobile data I can not.

Comment: In addition, Chrome can access to my server with mobile data too but other browsers and my application can't. This is the confusing part:(

Comment: I think you likely have several problems which are combining to make it harder to debug. As a start can you explain which, the server or the client, has switched to static IP and share some of the logs or the browser console you are seeing. This will help people understand the first issue.